# Como usar 2 listas para alterar o MySql via Python 3.x, neste caso

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, python-3.x, pandas

Boas pessoal, tudo bem?

Eu estou criando um script em Py pelo proprio COLAB pois preciso alterar o peso de vários produtos no WooCommerce, eu capturo o ID de um grupo de produtos baseado no tamanho 300ml, 150ml, etc... E em seguida para cada ID eu incluo o peso relativo à aquele produto no banco de dados.

O Script funcionou quando eu declarei o tamanho (300ml, 200ml, 150ml) e também o peso, porém tenho uma lista de 12 possibilidades de tamanho e seus pesos.

Criei duas listas uma onde possuem os TAMANHOS (que vão retornar os IDs dos produtos relativos a esse tamanho) e outa que possuem os PESOS.

Porém agora ele não funciona, e também não apresenta nenhum erro no Colab.

Acredito que seja um projeto que irá beneficiar muitos mais pra frente mas a principio segue o código:

```
import mysql.connector as sql
import pandas as pd

#DEFINIR PARAMETROS DE CONEXÃO
hostip = 'MEUIP'
dataname = 'MEUDB'
username = 'MEUUSER'
passworduser = 'MEUPW'

#DEFINIR AS CONDIÇÕES: 1 - TAMANHO DO PRODUTO NO TITULO (500ML) E 2 - PESO NO SISTEMA
prsearch = [70, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 450, 500, '1l', 1000, 'salon duo', 'salon trio']; #com ou sem o ml
prsub = [0.100, 0.130, 0.180, 0.230, 0.280, 0.330, 0.480, 0.530, 1.050, 1.050, 2.100, 3.150]; #peso em KG separado por . e não ,

#REALIZAR CONEXÃO COM DB
db_connection = sql.connect(host=hostip, database=dataname, user=username, password=passworduser)

db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
lp = 0
limit = len(prsearch)
while lp >= limit:
  lprs = prsearch[lp]
  db_cursor.execute("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_title LIKE '%{}%'".format(lprs))

#TRECHO PARA REMOVER AS VÍRGULAS ADICIONAIS DA TUPLA RETORNADA NO FETCHALL, 

  db_ids = [ x[0] for x in db_cursor.fetchall()] 

#QUE INTERFEREM NA BUSCA NO LOOP FOR ABAIXO. \/

  lpsb  = prsub[lp]
  for i in db_ids:
    db_cursor.execute("UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value`= %s WHERE `post_id` = %s AND `meta_key` = '_weight'"(lpsb,i))
  
  lp += 1

  print('Concluído! A chave: {}'.format(lprs))
```

Alguém consegue me iluminar com o que pode estar dando erro?
Além de não imprimir erro ele também não imprime o ultimo print dentro do loop.

Comment: O seu while nunca está sendo executado, altere para while lp <= limit:

Comment: Foi o que notei então eu simplifiquei ainda mais removendo o while para um for. Gratidão pela luz ai amigo!

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz uma adaptação pra simplificar o código e também tentar solucionar o problema, pelo fato de não apresentar erros deduzi que não funcionava.

Quando postei aqui achei que já tinha tentado de tudo nas ultimas 4 horas.

Segue a solução:

```
#DEFINIR AS CONDIÇÕES: 1 - TAMANHO DO PRODUTO NO TITULO (500ML) E 2 - PESO NO SISTEMA
prsearch = [70, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 450, 500, '1l', 1000, 'salon duo', 'salon trio']; #com ou sem o ml
prsub = [0.100, 0.130, 0.180, 0.230, 0.280, 0.330, 0.480, 0.530, 1.050, 1.050, 2.100, 3.150]; #peso em KG separado por . e não ,

#REALIZAR CONEXÃO COM DB
db_connection = sql.connect(host=hostip, database=dataname, user=username, password=passworduser) 
  
db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()

lp = 0
limit = len(prsearch)

for y in prsearch:

  db_cursor.execute("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_title LIKE '%{}%'".format(y))

  db_ids = [ x[0] for x in db_cursor.fetchall()]
  
  pos = prsearch.index(y)
  id = prsub[pos]
  for i in db_ids:
    db_cursor.execute("UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value`= {} WHERE `post_id` = {} AND `meta_key` = '_weight'".format(id,i))
  
  print('Concluído! A chave: {}'.format(y))
```